# What is song played when Ken is being tortured on seaons 1 episode 12?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

The song starts at 12:34 and is kind of discordant in the beginning. 
It hits the part of being a real piano at around 14:00.

I am looking specifically for the song that starts at 14:00

Answer (score 1):

The name of the song in the intro and episode 12  is unravel.

Comment: But I don't think that is what you are looking for

Comment: @user28546 Rather than substantially editing this answer, it would be better if you just posted an answer yourself. (Text: " 
The name of the song that debuted in the first episode as ending and in episode 12  is unravel by TK from Ling Tosite Sigure. The song's background music consists of instrumental play with guitar and piano. The song starts off as Tell, oh Tell me( English version). ")

Answer (score 0):

I believe the song itself is called Rize's melody, it has a start with discord and has piano throughout most of the song and is about 5 minutes long. the name could also be Original Sorrow is this the song you were looking for?[Song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg3i84IYGJ4)